# How do I open VM from command line with virsh

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization

I can start a Virtual machine from command line and can then connect through ssh, nut I need the ip address to do this. checking ifconfig gives the gateway but not the machine number.I have tried the following:-

brian@boris:~$ sudo virsh console ubuntu18.04

[sudo] password for brian:

Connected to domain ubuntu18.04

Escape character is ^]

From her it just hangs and I can't escape, I have to close the terminal. Is it possible to open a shell for the VM without SSH?

Comment: Are you asking about how to use virsh? Or are you asking how to disable sshd? Or is that a typo and you want headless virsh connecting *only* using ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virsh console <guestname>` that you tried gives you access to the serial console of the system. Which in your case already seems to have a misconfiguration issue as with a running guest you'd expect to see what is on the main console e.g. boot messages and later a login prompt. Although be aware that this does not "replay" content.
So if you enter `virsh console <guestname>` late in a livecycle there will be nothing printed. If the guest works in general and you press enter you will most likely see the login prompt appear. But this isn't the ssh connection you asked for.

I read your "*but I need the ip address to do this*" as your current main issue. If you have used the default setup then libvirt will have set up dhcp for your guest - in that case it can also tell you that, example:

```
$ virsh domifaddr focal
 Name       MAC address          Protocol     Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 vnet1      52:54:00:2d:4b:e8    ipv4         192.168.122.3/24
```

If you have set up your guest to be ssh enabled you can now use ssh to try to connect through it. If instead you have bridged your guest to an external network which does dhcp there it depends on that setup to find the guest IP "*from the outside*".